# Creating tabs shortcode

Tags: shortcode, tabs

```
<div id="tab-side-container">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#side-tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#side-tab2">The Second Tab</a></li>
  <li><a href="#side-tab3">Tab C</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="panel-container">
  <div id="side-tab1">
   <h2>Configurations</h2>
   <p>This example has the animation disabled, so tab-switching is instantaneous. It also sets the active class names to custom names for more control over CSS stylization.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="side-tab2">
   <h2>Heading 2</h2>
   <p>Stuff from the second tab.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="side-tab3">
   <h2>Heading 3</h2>
   <p>More stuff from the last tab.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

I'm trying to set a shortcode for tabs in WordPress without JavaScript, but PHP is not my strong point. I really need help with this.

Comment: Hi, there's an answer box just bellow ;)

Comment: need to wait 8 hours - less than 10 rep

Answer (score 1):

user2587741 posted an answer to their question inside the question:

> ```
> $tabs_divs = '';
>
> function tabs_group($atts, $content = null ) {
>     global $tabs_divs;
>
>     $tabs_divs = '';
>
>     $output = '<div id="tab-side-container"><ul';
>     $output.='>'.do_shortcode($content).'</ul>';
>     $output.= '<div class="panel-container">'.$tabs_divs.'</div>';
>
>     return $output;  
> }  
>
>
> function tab($atts, $content = null) {  
>     global $tabs_divs;
>
>     extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
>         'id' => '',
>         'title' => '', 
>     ), $atts));  
>
>     if(empty($id))
>         $id = 'side-tab'.rand(100,999);
>
>     $output = '
>         <li>
>             <a href="#'.$id.'">'.$title.'</a>
>         </li>
>     ';
>
>     $tabs_divs.= '<div id="'.$id.'">'.$content.'</div>';
>
>     return $output;
> }
>
> add_shortcode('tabs', 'tabs_group');
> add_shortcode('tab', 'tab');
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Creating tabs short code. Use bootstrap tab panel so must use bootstrap class in HTML and don't missing link bootstrap js and css.
**Code put in your current theme function.php file**   and use this **[tab_review]** 
More Info : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

```
function tab_custom() {
    $tab_data='';
    $tab_data.='<div id="tab-side-container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                <h2>Home</h2>
                <p>This example has the animation disabled, so tab-switching is instantaneous. It also sets the active class names to custom names for more control over CSS stylization.</p>
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
                <h2>Profile</h2>
                <p>This example has the animation disabled, so tab-switching is instantaneous. It also sets the active class names to custom names for more control over CSS stylization.</p>
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">
                <h2>Messages</h2>
                <p>This example has the animation disabled, so tab-switching is instantaneous. It also sets the active class names to custom names for more control over CSS stylization.</p>
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">
                <h2>Settings</h2>
                <p>This example has the animation disabled, so tab-switching is instantaneous. It also sets the active class names to custom names for more control over CSS stylization.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';
    return $tab_data;
}
add_shortcode( 'tab_review', 'tab_custom' );
```